# How to solve Graph API error "Rate Limiting" in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook total share count for 400 urls using Graph API.

Here is my code:

```
$posturl = get_permalink( $data->ID );
$json_stringUrl = ('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $posturl);
$json_string = file_get_contents($json_stringUrl);
```

But this return rate limit error after few hits. Please help me how i can solve this issue or i can use any another FB api.

Comment: sleep between the calls.

Comment: Already try sleep, but we can hit only 200 url once in a day according to FB rate limit. I have to get count for 2000 url in a single day

Comment: Where did you read 200 urls per day?

Answer (score 0):

Either cache the results and do less calls or let another platform do it for you: https://www.sharedcount.com/

I believe the free plan offers 10.000 calls per day.